# При удалении ветки, файлы также удаляются?

Tags: git

Проиндексировал изменения на ветке, но не создал коммит. Файлы куда-то пропали. Ветку, на которой были файлы, удалил. Можно ли их как-то восстановить?

Comment: Что значит "проиндексировал"? В чем выражается "удалена"? Ветка сама по себе не удаляется.

Comment: Использовал git add, файлы исчезли; ветку удалил сам.

Comment: некоторые IDE, как, например IntelliJ IDEA, и другие продукты Jetbrains, пишут свою, локальнюу историю всех изменений. Проверьте, возможно, ваш редактор тоже поддерживает Local History.

Comment: вообще-то программа *git* должна была отказаться удалять текущую ветку. вы использовали какую-то друую программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При удалении ветки файлы также удаляются?

Если это делать с консоли - то нет. Удаление ветки это просто удаление одного файла на 40 символов. Если удалять другими способами, можно и ОС удалить.

**Восстановление**

Странная ситуация. Скорее всего использовалась какая то "модная система разработки" или "крутые GUI тулы". Но допустим, что все так и есть.

Попробуем что то найти. Для начала запустим такую команду в текущем репозитории в баш консоли

```
 find .git/objects -type f -ls
```

появятся список файлов с странными длинными именами (где то так `.git/objects/1f/7a7a472abf3dd9643fd615f6da379c4acb3e3a`). По дате смотрите подходящие. Теперь, кода есть список таких, можно попробовать посмотреть их посмотреть.

```
git cat-file -p 1f7a7a472abf3dd9643fd615f6da379c4acb3e3a
```

(внимательно смотрите, как было в имени два символа слеш 38 символов, а стало 40 вместе)

больше деталей можно посмотреть [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

К сожалению, эти файлы потеряли имена, но содержимое их доступно.

Самое главное - не запускать `git gc` и различные GUI утилиты.

Также, следует заметить, что в некоторых утилитах (source tree) бывают странные ошибки, когда они отображают не то, что есть на самом деле.